# Perl tail logs in between servers

Tags: perl

I basically want to be able to send the apache log file line by line (tail) in between two servers (unidirectionally, from one two one), I want to use perl.

Any idea?, I would like be able to do things with each line of apache log in real time but in another server.

Thanks you!

Comment: How do you connect to the server in question? SSH? Is it a requirement that you use Perl or do you just want to?

Comment: I prefer use perl, the idea is that I want to send apache logs lines in real time from two server to an specific one, so from the receptor I will treat the logs in real time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Perl (you can probably wrap this up in a bit of Perl so you can manipulate the data), but netcat (or nc for short) (should be available on most systems).

On one server

```
tail -f filename | nc -l 12345
```

On the other server

```
nc hostname 12345
```

Of course you can use a different port number. So I guess in Perl you would exec these commands (ssh to the remote server etc.). Hopefully this has given you some ideas! nc has loads of options so you should be able to find something.

If you want to write netcat in Perl then that's a slightly different story.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [piped logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped). This way your perl script will get every log line on standard input and then it's up to you, how you are going to send them (SSH, FTP, HTTP or maybe even connect to SQL etc).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to tail the log file from the remote host via SFTP using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

The module contains a sample script implementing the remote tail: [sftp_tail.pl](https://github.com/salva/p5-Net-SFTP-Foreign/blob/master/samples/sftp_tail.pl)